# React Router v6 Button onclick Navigate vis class components

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-class-based-component

Trying to port an application from router v2 to router v6.

Everything I see everywhere is hooks.

Tried to make a custom withRouter, "Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component."

The button in question

```js
<YAButton
    onClick={this.goToForgotPassword.bind(this)}
    size="tiny"
    style={YALogin.styles.forgotPassword}
    type="text"
>
```

the function it calls

```js
    goToForgotPassword() {
        this.props.navigate(`/forgot${isEmail(this.state.emailAddress) ?
            `?emailAddress=${encodeURIComponent(this.state.emailAddress)}` :
            ''
        }`);
    }
```

the export at the bottom of the jsx file, perhaps something is amiss here?

```js
export default connect(YALogin.mapStateToProps, YALogin.mapDispatchToProps)(Radium(withRouter(YALogin)));
```

and my withRouter

```js
export const withRouter = (Component) => {
    const Wrapper = (props) => {
        const location = useLocation();
        const navigate = useNavigate();
        const params = useParams();
        return (
            <Component
                {...props}
                navigate={navigate}
                location={location}
                params={params}
            />
        );
    };

    return Wrapper;
};
```

Clearly I can't use hooks, but I also can't change the entire application over to function based components.

How do click "Forgot Password" button to go the

```js
`/forgot${isEmail(this.state.emailAddress) ?
            `?emailAddress=${encodeURIComponent(this.state.emailAddress)}` :
            ''
        }`
```

edit: The render().

```js
    render() {
        return (
            <main
                className="splash"
                style={{
                    backgroundImage: `url(${window.__configuration.cdn}/splash/splash.jpg)`
                }}
            >
                <form
                    className="stripped"
                    onSubmit={this.sendLoginRequest.bind(this)}
                >

                    {/* Render the application logo */}
                    <div className="dual-logo">
                        <img
                            src={`${window.__configuration.cdn}/logos/logo-redacted-y-negative.svg`}
                            className="redacted-logo"
                            alt="Weemarkable"
                        />
                        <div className="logo-divider"></div>
                        <img
                            src={`${window.__configuration.cdn}/logos/logo-weemarkable-negative-${Translator.getLang()}.svg`}
                            className="weemarkable-logo"
                            alt="Weemarkable"
                        />
                    </div>
                    {/* Set inner html to allow non-breaking-space tags to render */}
                    <p className="tagline"
                       dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: Translator.translate("General.Tagline")}}></p>

                    <fieldset>

                        {/* Render an alert if the login has failed for any reason */}
                        {
                            this.props.loginError !== null ?
                                <YAAlert type="E">
                                    <span>{this.state.errorMessage}</span>
                                </YAAlert> :
                                null
                        }

                        {/* Collect the email address from the user */}
                        <YAInput
                            type="email"
                            className="stripped-input"
                            noBaseStyles
                            onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, 'emailAddress')}
                            placeholder={Translator.translate("General.YourEmail")}
                            value={this.state.emailAddress}
                        />

                        {/* Collect the password from the user */}
                        <YAInput
                            type="password"
                            className="stripped-input"
                            noBaseStyles
                            onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, 'password')}
                            placeholder={Translator.translate("Password.Password")}
                            value={this.state.password}
                        />

                        <div style={YALogin.styles.controls}>

                            {/*  Button which submits the login request to the server */}
                            <div>
                                <YAInput
                                    type="submit"
                                    className={classNames('btn-stripped', {disabled: !this.isFormValid()})}
                                    noBaseStyles
                                    value={Translator.translate("MainPage.SignIn")}
                                />
                            </div>

                            {/* Button which takes the user to the forgot password screen */}
                            <div>
                                <YAButton
                                    onClick={() => useNavigate()(`/forgot${isEmail(this.state.emailAddress) ? `?emailAddress=${encodeURIComponent(this.state.emailAddress)}` : ''}`)}
                                    size="tiny"
                                    style={YALogin.styles.forgotPassword}
                                    type="text"
                                >
                                    {Translator.translate("MainPage.ForgotPassword")}
                                </YAButton>
                                |
                                <YAButton
                                    onClick={this.goToForgotPassword.bind(this)}
                                    size="tiny"
                                    style={YALogin.styles.forgotPassword}
                                    type="text"
                                >
                                    {Translator.translate("MainPage.TOU")}
                                </YAButton>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>

                {/* Render footer logo */}
                <footer className="brand-bar login">
                    <img
                        src={`${window.__configuration.cdn}/logos/logo-redacted-of-hamilton-${window.__configuration.langCode}.svg`}
                        className="footer-logo"
                        alt="redactedof redacted| redacted| Brantford"
                    />
                </footer>

            </main>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any issue with your custom `withRouter` HOC to inject the `navigate` function as a prop. What isn't working? Can you be more specific? Can you add more of this `YALogin` you are trying to decorate?

Comment: ```react-dom.development.js?61bb:14724 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.```

That is the error I'm getting.

I'll edit the post to include the Render() component.

When I click the "Forgot Password" button, it throws the above in the js console and doesn't redirect.

Comment: Where are you trying to use a React hook outside a function component or other custom hook? Oh, I see it, in the `YAButton` in the `onClick` you've `onClick={() => useNavigate()(\`/forgot${isEmail(this.state.emailAddress) ? \`?emailAddress=${encodeURIComponent(this.state.emailAddress)}\` : ''}\`)}`... You can't use the `useNavigate` hook there. Is this `render` method in the component you decorated with the custom `withRouter` HOC?

Comment: I must have accidentally ctrl+z'd that, because it WAS 

```onClick={this.goToForgotPassword.bind(this)}```

Bless you sir, I'd upvote you to the moon but I do not have 15 points.

Comment: No worries, it happens to everyone. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers and good luck.